# $f^{(n)}(z_0)>n!\, b_n$ and also $\lim (b_n)^{1/ n}\to\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits

$f$ is analytic, we need to show that it is not possible $f^{(n)}(z_0)>n! b_n\forall n=1,2\dots,\text{ where }\lim (b_n)^{1\over n}\to\infty$

From Taylor Series Expansion around $z_0$ we get $$f(z)=\sum {f^{(n)}(z_0)\over n!}(z-z_o)^n$$

and from Cauchys Integral Formula we get $$f^{(n)}(z_0)={n!\over 2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r} {f(z) dz\over (z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$

could anyone help me how to proceed?

**Added**

$R={1\over \lim sup |a_n|^{1\over n}}={(n!)^{1\over n}\over (f^{(n)}(z_0))^{1\over n}}> {(n!)^{1\over n}\over (n!)^{1\over n}(b_n)^{1\over n}}$

Comment: Hint: Think of the formula you use to find the radius of convergence and use your given inequality.

Comment: Radius of Convergent $R={1\over \lim sup |a_n|^{1\over n}}$

Comment: But how to get the contradiction?

Comment: The condition $(b_n)^{1/n}\rightarrow \infty$ forces the radius of convergence to be $0$, which is not possible for analytic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in the open region $\Omega$, and $z_0\in\Omega$, then there is a disk $D_r(z_0)\subset\Omega$, $r>0$, which implies that $f$ can be expressed as a power series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n,
$$
with radius of convergence at least $r$. The radius of convergence of the above is equal to $R=1/\ell$, where $\ell$ is given by (root test)
$$
\ell=\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} 
\frac{|f^{(n)}(z_0)|^{1/n}}{(n!)^{1/n}}.
$$
Now, if $R>0$, then $\ell<\infty$, which implies that $\displaystyle\frac{|f^{(n)}(z_0))|^{1/n}}{(n!)^{1/n}}$ is bounded, say by some $M>0$. Then
$$
\big|\,f^{(n)}{(z_0)}\,\big|\le M^n n!
$$